# In Django DRFs' `ListCreateAPIView` POST method, how do we get the pk of a model field?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

I have a simple `ModelSerializer` which looks like this:

```
class DBaaSOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DBaaSOrder
        fields = '__all__'
```

The above has also some `validate` methods which are not relevant for this question.

Now, I'm using the above serializer in a Class-Based View like this:

```
class DBaaSOrderView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = DBaaSOrderSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        usd = UsdDBActions()
        orders = DBaaSOrder.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('updated_at')

        for change_ref, change_status, updated_at in orders.values_list('change_ref', 'change_status', 'updated_at'):
            usd_change_status = usd.get_rfc_status(change_ref)
            usd_change_updated_at = usd.get_last_mod_date(change_ref)

            if change_status != usd_change_status:
                orders.filter(change_ref=change_ref).update(change_status=usd_change_status)

            if updated_at != usd_change_updated_at:
                orders.filter(change_ref=change_ref).update(updated_at=usd_change_updated_at)

        return orders.filter(change_status__in=VALID_USD_STATUSES)[:MAX_ORDERS]

    @staticmethod
    def get_dns(value):
        dns_records = DNS.objects.all()
        for dns in dns_records:
            if dns.server in value and dns.domain in value:
                return dns

    @staticmethod
    def get_backup_plan(value):
        backup_plans = BackupPlan.objects.all()
        for backup_plan in backup_plans:
            if backup_plan.customer_policy_name in value and backup_plan.retention in value:
                return backup_plan

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        data['user'] = request.user.pk

        dns_record = self.get_dns(data['dns'])
        backup_plan = self.get_backup_plan(data['backup'])

        dns_record_pk = dns_record.pk
        backup_plan_pk = backup_plan.pk

        data['dns'] = dns_record_pk
        data['backup'] = backup_plan_pk

        serializer = DBaaSOrderSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            usd = UsdDBActions()
            data = request.data

            usd_data = {
                'organization': int(data['organization_pk']),
                'category': 'SSC.DBM.DB.ADD',
                'assignee': request.user.username,
            }

            response = usd.create_rfc(usd_data)

            try:
                result = response.json()

                if result['code'] == 200:
                    change_ref = int(response.json()['reference_number'])

                    data['user'] = request.user
                    data['change_ref'] = int(response.json()['reference_number'])
                    data['change_status'] = usd.get_rfc_status(change_ref)
                    data['dns'] = dns_record
                    data['backup'] = backup_plan

                    DBaaSOrder.objects.create(**data)

                    return Response({
                        'message': f"The RFC {data['change_ref']} has been successfully created!",
                        'code': 200
                    })
```

Everything works as expected but what I don't like about this is that I have the 2 methods `get_dns()` and `get_backup_plan()` to get the actual model object of the `dns` or `backup` fields. Isn't there an easier way to do this?

The reason for doing this is:

- here, `serializer = DBaaSOrderSerializer(data=data)`, `data` should contain the `pk` of the field;
- here, `DBaaSOrder.objects.create(**data)`, `data` should contain the instance of the model field;

More, `dns` and `backup` are foreign keys:

```
class DNS(models.Model):
    server = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.server} - {self.domain}'


class BackupPlan(models.Model):
    customer_policy_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    retention = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.customer_policy_name} - {self.retention}'
```

The main model looks like this:

```
class DBaaSOrder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dns = models.ForeignKey(DNS, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    backup = models.ForeignKey(BackupPlan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # ... other fields here
```

Comment: What does `data['dns']` look like?

Comment: @DanielRoseman `data['dns']` is a `str`. It's basically `f'{self.server} - {self.domain}'`. E.g.: `data['dns'] = 192.168.0.1 - test.domain.com`. It's also the same for `backup`.

Comment: If anyone thinks there's anything that could be simplified/improved apart from what I've asked feel free to mention it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two related issues here. First is where you put the logic to turn "192.168.0.1 - test.domain.com" into an instance of DNS. Second is how you do that database lookup.

This sort of thing always belongs on the serializer; that is the code that is responsible for turning the received data into the right format. This specific logic belongs in a validation method; these have the name `validate_<fieldname>`, so we need `validate_dns` and `validate_backup`.

The way you are doing the db lookup is pretty inefficient at the moment. We can do it much more simply by splitting the input and then doing a direct db query using that data.

In order to make all this work we need to override the definition of those fields to make them CharFields, so that they accept arbitrary data. The validate method will then take care of converting them to the actual model instances.

So:

```
class DBaaSOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    dns = serializers.CharField()
    backup = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = DBaaSOrder
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate_dns(self, value):
        try:
            server, domain = value.split(' - ')
        except ValueError:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('not in correct format')
        try:
            instance = DNS.objects.get(server=server, domain=domain)
        except DNS.DoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('no matching DNS')
        return instance

    def validate_backup(self, value):
        ... similar to above...
```

Now you can get rid of the custom logic in `post`.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. I managed to understand what validation does in the serializer, but there's still a small problem. When I'm doing `DBaaSOrder.objects.create(**data)` I get: `DBaaSOrder.dns must be a "DNS" instance`. So, how do I get the DNS instance in the POST?

Comment: `data` is the original data that you passed in. The validated data is in `validated_data`, but really you shouldn't be changing it outside of the serializer, and you should create your object by doing `serializer.save()`.

Comment: I'm getting confused about what should be inside the `post()` method of the view and what should be inside the `save()` method in the serializer. I'd really appreciate some guidence because the documentation wasn't _too_ specific about this